# unity - как реализовать подгрузку "уровня" из сети из своей игры?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Дано:

- Игра написанная на юнити
- Сервер с неким пхп скриптом, который может перенаправить на некий файл для предназначенный для юнити

Вопросы:

- Как релизовать "плагин" с левелом и всеми ресурсами под игрушку?
- Как реализовать запрос и скачку этого плагина?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Скачивать как и обычные файлы, используя `UnityWebRequest`, а затем складывать куда-то.
2. Я не помню, возможно ли целую сцену из файла загрузить.

Я могу сказать, как мы делаем.

1. В Unity3d создаём сцену, потом сериализуем её в json или бинарный файл.
2. Заливаем на сервер.
3. Клиент скачивает файл, создаёт пустую сцену, а потом на основе этого файла добавляет объекты на сцену.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Думаю, что разберусь когда доберусь до дела) Если чесно, не ожидал такого быстрого ответа на этот вопрос. Возможно, позже возникнут доп.вопросы. Если не против, задам тогда же сюда в коменты :)

Comment: @Andrew всегда рад помочь. Лучше отдельным вопросом задавать, если захотите узнать что-то конкретное ^_^

Comment: А возможна ли сериализация ряда файлов? Например, префаб + все ресурсы префаба (анимации, 3д модели, текстуры) ? Использовал ли assetBundle? Если да, то где есть актуальная информация по них?

Comment: @Andrew именно сами текстуры или параметры текстуры?

Comment: Именно текстуры. Мне НЕ нужно что бы в самой апликухе хранились модели и их текстуры. Мне нужно их подгружать с интернета.

Comment: @Andrew https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html